# phpExcel create writer from file

Tags: php, phpexcel

Suppose I have a file named **abc.xls**

I have some values in some columns in that file with macro's and formulas.

How can I add some more values to that file using **phpExcel.** without losing the macro's and formulas in it?

Like for example I want to set the value of the **cell A5** as the string **"Testing"**.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. PHPExcel cannot handle macros, although you should have no problems with formulae unless they use UDFs. Try using COM, or PUNA instead